# Exception handling in Chrome extensions

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I can't seem to find anything in the Chrome extension documentation about exception handling. All the asynchronous apis makes it very difficult without littering the code with try / catch statements everywhere..

How can I add a global exception handler to my background page that'll allow me to do some resource cleanup in the case of an exception?

Comment: There are some variables which are set during an error or exception and there are no explicit error handling methods as such till date. If you want to do resource clean up you can put your code in some management event handler

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can get the error in the execute script callback with [`chrome.runtime.lastError`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#property-lastError):

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, details, function() {
    if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
       var errorMsg = chrome.runtime.lastError.message
       if (errorMsg == "Cannot access a chrome:// URL") {
           // Error handling here
       }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 4):

I haven't been able to find a global error handler but I was able to come up with a solution that works just as well.

It does depend on what methods you're calling though. Most of my errors came from calling `chrome.tabs.executeScript()` on a `chrome://` page or a chrome webstore page. The last parameter of this function is a callback that contains a `results` array. I found that if this was `undefined` I was getting an error back. This way I was able to set up a simple error handling function to notify the user when there was an error.

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: '/path/to/file.js'}, function(results) {
    if (results === undefined) {
        // Fire error handling code
    }
});
```

Again, Idk if this is applicable with the methods that you're calling but I was able to do what I wanted this way.